# Apache Nginx Varnish listening port Magento 2

Tags: magento2, nginx, varnish, apache

Centos 6

Already using Apache + Nginx  on my Magento 1 sites on a dedicated server

For a Magento 2.2 site I want to run varnish

However after installing varnish - i saw in the instructions need to change listening port-

What I did is to keep apache on 8080 and change Nginx from 80 to 446 (443 is being using for SSL)   and changed inside [Home]/etc/varnish default.vcl

from 8080 to 80

Stopped and Restarted Apache Nginx and Varnish however when I went to open the websites none of them are able to connect -

I checked varnish port

ps aux | grep varnish

Output I get is

[root@server ~]# ps aux | grep varnish
varnish   6393  0.0  0.0  28932  5204 ?        SLs  15:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/varni                                                                                                 shd -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -p thread_pool_min=50                                                                                                  -p thread_pool_max=1000 -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256M -P /var/run/varni                                                                                                 sh.pid
varnish   6403  0.0  0.7 316840 116444 ?       SLl  15:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/varni                                                                                                 shd -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -p thread_pool_min=50                                                                                                  -p thread_pool_max=1000 -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256M -P /var/run/varni                                                                                                 sh.pid
root     11434  0.0  0.0 103320   904 pts/0    S+   16:07   0:00 grep varnish
[root@server ~]#

Shows 6081 and 6082 but not the port 80 I set

I read some other posts with people with similar problems but I dont have on my server the file changes mentioned in those server locations.

One more thing is that before today I has Varnish 2.1 but today I installed 5.2   - i didn't remoeve the version 2.1 but just followed instructions to install the 5.2 version - so can this be the cause and where else would varnish be getting those values for port setting?

Nginx - doesnt seem to work unless it's on port 80

Please can anyone help asap stuck on this all day

Comment: I managed to find another file that was here  [Home]/etc/sysconfig  filename varnish
 now it is matching same port number specified in default.vcl  Please can someone clarify in default.vcl do i put localhost or the ip address of the domain name I want to use varnish for - backend default  at the moment it is like this {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8081";      what I want to be able to do is enable varnish only for a particular domain which has the magento 2 site and keep the other magento 1 sites working on different domain using ngix   is this possible?

Comment: just to add i changed the varnish port to 8081 and reset nginx to  80 to open up live sites on the server which stopped working after i changed the nginx port

Answer (score 0):

use only one - apache or nginx. with varnish.

you have:

```
user -> nginx:80 -> nginx:443 -> vanish:8081 -> nginx:8080
```

one domain you proxy pass request back to varnish, for another domain you dont proxy pass, request goes to nginx only. that simple.